# How to find the name of the function call in a class file using ASM?

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

Here I have a simple add java program

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static int add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a+b;
    }
    public static void main(String [] argv)
    {
        String a="Hello world";
    int b=499,c=599;
    int v= add(b,c);
    }
}
```

Now I am using a manipulation program to manipulate the class file of the java program.

```
package com.seriouscompany.program;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;
import java.util.jar.JarOutputStream;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter;
import org.objectweb.asm.tree.AbstractInsnNode;
import org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode;
import org.objectweb.asm.tree.LdcInsnNode;
import org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode;

public class Manipulator {

    //!!Change this to the path to your application's path!!
    public static final File PROGRAM_APPLICATION_JAR = new File("C:\\Users\\jayarasr\\Desktop\\SeriousProgram.jar");    
    private static List<ClassNode> classNodes = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        PrintStream o = new PrintStream(new File("A.txt"));
        System.setOut(o);
        classNodes = load(PROGRAM_APPLICATION_JAR);

        for(ClassNode classNode : classNodes) {
            System.out.println("------------------");
            System.out.println("Class Node :"+classNode.name);
            for(Object methodNodeObj : classNode.methods) {
                MethodNode methodNode = (MethodNode)methodNodeObj;
                System.out.println("Method Node  :"+methodNode.name);
             //   if(methodNode.name.toString()=="main") {}
                for(AbstractInsnNode abstractInsnNode : methodNode.instructions.toArray()) {
                    System.out.println("Abstract : "+abstractInsnNode.getOpcode());
                     if(abstractInsnNode instanceof LdcInsnNode) {
                        LdcInsnNode ldcInsn = (LdcInsnNode)abstractInsnNode;
                        System.out.println("Value :"+ldcInsn.cst);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        save(new File(PROGRAM_APPLICATION_JAR.getAbsolutePath().replace(".jar", "dumped.jar")), classNodes);
    }

    public static void save(File jar, final List<ClassNode> nodes) {
        try {
            try(final JarOutputStream output = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(jar))) {
                for(ClassNode element : nodes) {
                    ClassWriter writer = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);
                    output.putNextEntry(new JarEntry(element.name.replaceAll("\\.", "/") + ".class"));
                    output.write(writer.toByteArray());
                    output.closeEntry();
                }
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static List<ClassNode> load(File file) {
        try {
            JarFile jar = new JarFile(file);
            List<ClassNode> list = new ArrayList<>();
            Enumeration<JarEntry> enumeration = jar.entries();
            while(enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
                JarEntry next = enumeration.nextElement();
                if(next.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
                    ClassReader reader = new ClassReader(jar.getInputStream(next));
                    ClassNode node = new ClassNode();
                    reader.accept(node, ClassReader.SKIP_DEBUG | ClassReader.SKIP_FRAMES);
                    list.add(node);
                }
            }
            jar.close();
            return list;
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here I am able to print the class name and the method names and the constant values.
Now my query is how to print the variable names, called functions name(invoked one)(I can find the opcodes only)
I read the documentation of ASM, and travelled to understand till this,
please help me to find the above mentioned query.

Answer (score 0):

To get hold of the invoked method's name, you have to check the properties of the `MethodNodeInsn` which defines the owner, method name and descriptor of any called method. To get hold of the variable names, you need to read the [local variable table](http://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/tree/LocalVariableNode.html) what is debug information which is not necessarily present in all classes.